# Why doesn't gvim set the font correctly?

Tags: vim, editor, text-editor

I am trying to configure gvim font on linux in `.vimrc` but it produces strange results.
To make gvim use "Liberation Mono" I added `set guifont=LiberationMono: h12`. It gets applied but does not recognize `:h12` option and output:

```
Error detected while processing /home/tastyminerals/.vimrc:
line   44:
E518: Unknown option: h12
```

But I am ok with the result since the font gets applied.
[image]

However when I correct the line to `set guifont=LiberationMono:h12` gvim does not complain but the font gets changed to this:

[image]

This is not "Liberation Mono" of course, this thing happens with any other font I try to use. 
Why does the font get changed to some strange monospaced variant? How can I configure the font correctly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set the default font size on vim?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17508542/how-to-set-the-default-font-size-on-vim)

Comment: no, I already tried that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I managed to resolve the issue by correcting the font setting in `~/.vimrc`

```
set guifont=LiberationMono\ 12
```

[image]

Comment: If ppl carefully read help manuals stackoverflow would not exist ;)

Comment: similar issue with win10 gVim, resolved with `set guifont=Fira\ Mono\ Medium:h10`