# vim on ultra-high display (3200-1800) on Windows 8

Tags: vim, windows-8.1

gvim for windows has tiny text and icons on my ultra-HD Dell laptop (3200-1800) . In fact, it is barely readable. How does one change gvim gui fonts and increases the icons to obtain readable text on a high resolution, windows 8 laptop?

Comment: [How to set the Default Font size in vim](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17508781/1890567)

Comment: Your problem, and thus your question, is unrelated to the kind of computer you use, its brand, the resolution of its display, its operating system *and* programming.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. Increasing gui fonts helped massively. gvim icons still remain tiny but they are used rarely anyway. Thanks for the advice and help.

Comment: I don't see this question as a duplicate of the "How to set the default font size on vim?" question.  This is a PPI awareness issue with VIM, a broader problem than font size. The workaround (and it is a workaround because the icon are still tiny) happens to have the same answer as "How to set the default font size on vim" question, but it is a different question.

Comment: I agree that this is not a duplicate. I'll add here that in addition to increasing the font size, it may be desired to disable the toolbar using `set guioptions-=T`

Comment: I don't understand why this is duplicate either but I found the answer in this forum at the bottom. Basically, right click on your gvim.exe file , go to properties, in compatibility tab under settings tick the override high dpi ..by' and change the drop down box to 'system enhanced'. This also applies to other programs for which you are facing the same issue. https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/1059

Answer (score 6):

you should configure you font size, one possible solution is is like this(you can put it in your vimrc):

```
set guifont=Consolas:h13
```

"Consolas" is the font name and "h13" is the font size, you should change 13 to a proper number~

Answer (score 2):

(I'm not sure about Windows, but...)

It really depends. If you're using vim from a terminal emulator the settings must be changed in your terminal emulator (let's say PuTTy).

But if you're using GVIM, then use `:set guifont font\ name\ size` to specify the font size. 
In order to check witch font and size you're using, simple call `:set guifont` and it will promt you with the current settings

In my case I use the following: `:set guifont=Ubuntu\ Mono\ 18`

Comment: On (many? some?) platforms, you can also use `set guifont=*` in gVim to pop open the system's font selection facility, so you can do it visually. Then, when you have your .vimrc open, type "set guifont=" followed by ctrl-R, =, "&guifont", enter and you'll get the mostly-correct text inserted. (You'll need to put backslashes before the spaces but otherwise it'll give you the font name and other attributes you specify).