# vim: font size and color settings not working for me, vim 7.4

Tags: vim

I'm using vim 7.4 on cygwin 64.   Some of the .vimrc settings work for me, specifically lines 1-3, and line 7.

```
  1 set number
  2 set mouse=a
  3 highlight normal ctermfg=LightGray
  4 highlight Comment ctermbg=DarkGray ctermfg=LightMagenta
  5 highlight CursorLine ctermbg=Blue
  6 set guifont=Monospace:h35
  7 set numberwidth=4
```

In order of importance:

- I'm trying to change my font-size, line 6 appears to have no effect.
- Making the cursor line a different color isn't working.
- My comments are for bash scripts, so the line starts with a "#", perhaps vim doesn't recognize?

I set the font size [per this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17508542/how-to-set-the-default-font-size-on-vim).

Comment: it seems you are quite new in vim. things are more complicated than that. vim runs inside of a terminal, so your terminal settings come first. so your fonts won't work in the first place. then, vim runs its configuration in different order, your way of twisting comment color won't work since it gets reconfigured afterwards. search around and get your head into it first.

Comment: Vim script uses `"` as a comment starting token, which is a singular double quote.

Answer (score 1):

Font size are only for GUI version of vim. In terminal, if you want to change the fonts size, is by change the font of the terminal. In window, the terminal used ussaly "cmd". See http://www.wikihow.com/Customize-the-Font-in-Windows-Command-Prompt to change the cmd font-size you can see the font in vim is also change.

Comment: Thanks.  Can you tell me your quick thoughts on how notepad++ WITH VI PLUGIN compares to VIM, or perhaps GVIM, which I haven't tried yet.

Comment: I never used notepad++ with vi plugin. But I think I wouldn't like it. The best thing I liked about vim is the plugin (vundle or phatogen). And I don't think the "real vim plugin" will works in notepad++.