# GVIM Settings in Centos7

Tags: vim

I have installed gvim in Centos7. But the gvim default font and size is not suitable for me as it is small and and wide. I am not able to find gvim setting to tweak. Any help please?

I tried /etc/vimrc, but it's for vim not for gvim and secondly it can't be open for write.

Comment: What about *Edit -> Select Font...*? You could also read `:help gui-font` ... or find out where Vim is looking for your configuration with `:help vimrc`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I set the default font size in Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17508542/how-do-i-set-the-default-font-size-in-vim)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this can help you: I have currently a `.gvimrc` file under my `/home` directory, that sets my preferences for fonts or *Copy-Paste* shortcuts:

```bash
cat ~/.gvimrc
```

````
set guifont=Monospace\ Regular\ 12
set lines=35 columns=120
set guicursor+=a:blinkon0

vmap <C-c> "+yi
vmap <C-x> "+c
vmap <C-v> c<ESC>"+p
imap <C-v> <C-r><C-o>+

function! MathAndLiquid()
    "" Define certain regions
    " Block math. Look for "$$[anything]$$"
    syn region math start=/\$\$/ end=/\$\$/
    " inline math. Look for "$[not $][anything]$"
    syn match math_block '\$[^$].\{-}\$'

    " Liquid single line. Look for "{%[anything]%}"
    syn match liquid '{%.*%}'
    " Liquid multiline. Look for "{%[anything]%}[anything]{%[anything]%}"
    syn region highlight_block start='{% highlight .*%}' end='{%.*%}'
    " Fenced code blocks, used in GitHub Flavored Markdown (GFM)
    syn region highlight_block start='```' end='```'

    "" Actually highlight those regions.
    hi link math Statement
    hi link liquid Statement
    hi link highlight_block Function
    hi link math_block Function
endfunction

" Call everytime we open a Markdown file
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile,BufEnter *.md,*.markdown call MathAndLiquid()
````

Comment: Why all the noise? The one line with `set guifont=...` does it.